# Validate the input field for existing item in object array?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

in my todo list i dont want user to input same todos again again... 
but my problem is, when i enter something for example (test) first time and than i enter (test2) and than i enter (test) again, so its taking a value.... how to validate properly....

**fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/LaL7h6Lv/1/

**html**

> ```
> <div ng-app="todoApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
>         <ul>
>           <li ng-repeat="todoItem in todoItems">{{todoItem.name}}</li>
>         </ul>
>     <form ng-submit="addItem()">
>         <input type="text" ng-model="newItem">
>         <input type="submit" name="go">
>     </form>
>     </div>
> ```

**angularjs**

> ```
> angular.module("todoApp", [])
> .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
>
>   $scope.todoItems = [{'name' : 'akshay'}];
>   $scope.test = false;
>
>   $scope.addItem = function(){
>       if($scope.newItem){
>           $scope.checkRepeatTodo();
>           if($scope.test == true){
>               $scope.todoItems.push({'name':$scope.newItem});
>               $scope.newItem = '';
>           }else{
>               alert('same todo');
>               $scope.test = false;
>           }
>       }else{
>           alert('fill the form');
>       }
>   };
>
>   $scope.checkRepeatTodo = function(){
>       $scope.todoItems.filter(function(item){
>           if($scope.newItem === item.name){
>               $scope.test = false;
>           }else{
>               $scope.test = true;
>           }
>       });
>   };
> }]);
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `$scope.test` value, you override the value to true when it filters down the 3rd item.

See the [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LaL7h6Lv/3/)

**Alternative:**

Make a javascript function rather than one in $scope and call that function return if its a valid entry or not.

This eliminates the need to have `$scope.test` and `$scope.checkRepeatTodo` as they do nothing of importance.

```
function checkRepeatTodo() {
  var valid = true;
     $scope.todoItems.filter(function(item){
       if($scope.newItem === item.name){
            return valid = false;
        }
    });
  return valid;
};
```

And use the same as:

```
if(checkRepeatTodo()){
    $scope.todoItems.push({'name':$scope.newItem});
    $scope.newItem = '';
}
else{
 alert('same todo');
}
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/LaL7h6Lv/4/http://)